# trying to load zero bits into register is verilog

Tags: verilog

im using modelsim with verilog
im currently trying to build a 32bit multiplier using an 8bit multiplier. 
im deviding the multiplication into 16 stages where in each stage I multiply 8 bits from one number with 8 bits of the other number ,thus overall covering 2 entire 32bit numbers.
i've encountered a problem when trying to load a "zero-byte" (8 bits of zeros which are on certain place in ine number), the register which is in charge of keeping these bits doesnt load the zeroes and instead keeps the last 8 bit number which is not zero. how do i force this register into storing zeroes.
i'm adding my code.
thanks a lot.

```
reg [8:0] outmuxa,outmuxb;
always @(a_sel or b_sel) begin
    case(a_sel) 
        00:outmuxa={1'b0,a[7:0]};
        01:outmuxa={1'b0,a[15:8]};
        10:outmuxa={1'b0,a[23:16]};
        11:outmuxa={1'b0,a[31:24]};
        endcase
    case(b_sel) 
        00:outmuxb={1'b0,b[7:0]};
        01:outmuxb={1'b0,b[15:8]};
        10:outmuxb={1'b0,b[23:16]};
        11:outmuxb={1'b0,b[31:24]};
        endcase
    end
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere you're attempting to assign an 8-bit width 0 to `outmuxa` or `outmuxb`. Can you clarify what conditions for `a_sel` and `b_sel` you want to do that?

Comment: for example, if the bits in location b[15:8] are all zeroes, than outmuxb won't change to all zeroes but instead keep the bits of b[7:0].

Answer (score 3):

I see two problems here:

1. Your sensitivity statement:

   ```
   always @(a_sel or b_sel) begin
   ```

   does not include the signals `a` or `b` which are referenced in the `always` block. This will cause your multiplexer to only update its output when `a_sel` or `b_sel` changes, not when an input changes. (This is unlikely to be synthesizable in hardware!)

   All modern versions of Verilog support `always @(*)`, which is sensitive to all signals referenced within the block. Use that instead.
2. Your `case` statements refer to `10` and `11`. Numbers in Verilog are interpreted as decimal by default, so your `case` is interpreted as covering zero, one, ten, and eleven, and using default behavior (another latch!) for all other values.

   If you want your `case` to cover the four possible values of a 2-bit signal -- which I'm pretty sure you do! -- prefix the case values with `'b` (e.g, `2'b10`). Otherwise, add a `default:` case.